# Rrounded surface between I have a closed loop of vertices. How do I approach this?

Tags: modeling, mesh, loop

I've established a loop of vertices however I have no clue how to create a rounded/curvy surface between them such that it bulges outwards slightly and meshes naturally.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Would  Ctrl-F > _Grid Fill_ do it for you? ( you may have to arrange for an even number of edges)

Comment: Not really but thank you! While *Grid Fill* would work to *fill* the surface between them, it won't really help me get a rounded surface (sorta like a half-sphere looking structure). At the very least i have no clue where to take it from there.

Comment: The question is hard to answer because it's not clear what this should look like. Ok, it should be a half-sphere. But why is there a mesh line? Well, you can use another sphere object, sculpt it so that it fits the hole, and then shrinkwrap the grid-filled area to this sphere object. Assign the vertices to a vertex group to control the shrinkwrap modifier.